# Spring Boot Hibernate Query timeout on Weblogic

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, weblogic

I have a Spring Boot (1.5.5) application using Hibernate (5.4.0) to query Oracle database. The application is deployed on WebLogic 12c. One of its query sometimes (50%) timed out (timeout set to 2 minutes). This query is to join two tables (one of the tables has 25 million rows; the other has 800K rows), aggregate and get the count on a column.

When the application runs on Tomcat (which comes with SpringBoot), this query always works fine. I also check the execution plan and the query is fast enough (10 seconds on Oracle SQL developer).

I wonder why sometimes this query timed out when the application runs on WebLogic.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: looks like one is slower than the other?

Comment: Might be different JPA behaviour regarding eager / lazy loading?

Comment: see : https://www.devconnectprogram.com/forums/posts/list/1286.page

Comment: I am using NamedNativeQuery       
@NamedNativeQuery(
  name = "countMeasure",
  query = "SELECT hr.DIRECT_ID as USER_ID, COUNT(ue.USER_NAME) AS EVENT_COUNT, ue.EVENT_CODE FROM HR_HIERARCHY hr, USAGE_EVENT ue WHERE (hr.USER_ID = :userId) AND (ue.USER_NAME = hr.REPORTEE_EMAIL) AND (ue.EVENT_TIME BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate) AND ue.EVENT_CODE IN ('CONTACT', 'NOTE' ) GROUP BY hr.DIRECT_ID, ue.EVENT_CODE", resultSetMapping ="evaluationMappingFromCountMeasure", resultClass = Measure.class)

Comment: @asyard thank you. My app is using JNDI for the datasource (no user/password). The entityManager Bean is configured as, 
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource ds) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(ds);
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"com...."});
    JpaVendorAdapter va = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(va);
    em.setJpaProperties(other()); //hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect;
    return em;
  }

Comment: @Mick that is a good point although it seems by default it is Lazy load. Let me try with lazy loading annotation. TTYL.

Comment: Also, have you tried using another version of Weblogic (eg 11g) ?

Comment: @asyard no, I have not. I only have Weblogic 12c for me to use.